# Laravel global scope on retrieving a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm retrieving `Events` from the database and every time I get events from the database I want to check `where active_from <= today`.

How am I able to define a global scope which will be used when I retrieve a model?

Comment: check out http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: @Anam I've seen it, but I can't find how I'll be able to specify to execute it when I try to get a model.

Comment: Here's how it's done http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trait like EventsTrait and inside that trait, add a bootEventTrait function that will add a global scope like EventsScope. Use SoftDeletingTrait as pattern.

EventTrait

```
trait EventsTrait {

    public static function bootEventsTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new EventsScope);
    }

}
```

EventScope

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class EventScope implements ScopeInterface {

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->where("active_from","<=", "today");
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {
        // remove scope
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global scope (eg: is_active) to the Event model.

```
// App\Event.php

use Carbon\Carbon;

public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('is_active', function($builder){
            $builder->where('active_from', '<=', Carbon::now());
    })

}
```